# Compute the dimension of the space of quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

We were asked the following:

"Compute the dimension of the space of quadratic forms on $V=\mathbb{R^2}.$ Compute also the dimension of the space of symetric forms on $\mathbb{R^2}$, $S^2\mathbb{R^2}$. Compute also the dimension of the space of skew-symmetric forms $\Lambda^2\mathbb{R^2}$."

I'm not quite sure how to compute the dimension of these spaces. I wouldn't know how to do the only ways I know how, by using Rank-Nullity or finding a basis for the spaces.

Comment: You will want to try coming up with a basis. Do you know how to give an explicit description of what a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ looks like?  If not, what is your definition of a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I believe a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R^2}$ takes the form $Q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, but I don't know how to use this information to come up with a basis.

Comment: Let's step back and try to guess the answer before we actually prove it rigorously.  Intuitively, you can think of the dimension of a space as the number of scalar parameters that you need to describe an element of it.  How many parameters would you say you need to describe a quadratic form?

Comment: @EricWofsey In $\mathbb{R^2}$, would you need 2 parameters?

Comment: Why $2$ parameters?

Comment: @EricWofsey Intuitively I think it makes sense, because $\mathbb{R^2}$ only has 2 dimensions, and so one can use 2 scalars with a basis to describe any element of the space.

Comment: Oh, sure.  But I was asking about quadratic forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$, not elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @EricWofsey So are you talking about the scalars $a, b, \text{and } c$?

Comment: Right.  So now, can you see how to find a basis corresponding to those three parameters?

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm afraid that's where I get a bit more confused. How would I go about thinking about finding a basis for this?

Comment: Can you see any particular three quadratic forms that span all of the quadratic forms?  If you have a quadratic form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, can you see a way to express it as a linear combination of some particular three quadratic forms?

Comment: Are the three quadratic forms you're referring to $ax^2, bxy,$ and $cy^2$? I suppose by choice of scalar, one could obtain any quadratic form?

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the discussion in the comments: any quadratic form is of the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, and so it can be uniquely written as a linear combination of $x^2$, $xy$, and $y^2$ (namely, with the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$).  This means $\{x^2,xy,y^2\}$ is a basis, so the dimension is $3$.

For (skew-)symmetric forms you can do something similar.  I don't know exactly what definition of them you are using, but you should be able to write them in a form where they manifestly depend on some number of parameters, and then by writing any form as a linear combination of some basic forms with these parameters as coefficients, you get a basis.